# Do bountied questions automatically expire?

Tags: discussion, meta

I'm curious what happens to bountied questions from users that appear to have stopped using this platform. I recently answered a question (along with 2 others) from a user that hasn't logged in since July. Is there a definitive rule on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant portion of the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) text is:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: Interesting...in the case from which my question arose, this did not happen. But it's all good; again, my thanks.

Comment: @ajgringo619 So, yes, bounties should expire after 7 days. However, some sites have a meta post with a [List of bounties with no deadline](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/629/800). The downside of that approach is that it is hard to find out about these bounties if that post is not [meta-tag:featured] on meta.

Comment: I should have clarified my post. The bounty *was* awarded, just not the way it was explained to me.

Comment: @ajgringo619 If it's [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515581/could-not-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb), it looks to me like the OP may have manually awarded the bounty to a specific answer before the grace period expired.

Comment: That's possible; thanks again.